# LispWorks cannot open in OS X El Capitan

Tags: common-lisp, lispworks

The app icon just keeps bouncing for a few minutes after I click it, and then stop and nothing is show. The app then becomes “Not Responding.”

According to the [document](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/RNIG/html/readme-13.htm), I should be asked to select GUI options, but that didn't happen during the installation process.

I think it has to do with GUI.
So I installed/updated X11, but it's still not working even after that.

I'm using the LispWorks 6.1.1 Personal Edition.

Comment: Have you entered your serial number / license data?

Comment: Best to contact their support.

Comment: Thanks, @RainerJoswig!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Lispworks' support team.
It turned out it's because my mac name has a non-ASICC char `'` (it was `XXX's Macbook Pro`).
Changing the computer's name using `sudo scutil --set HostName name-you want` fixed the issue.